# Vulas startup failed with an exception in the backend

Tags: vulas

I am trying to run the [Vulas](https://github.com/SAP/vulnerability-assessment-tool) docker setup on one of our VMs. I followed [this](https://github.com/SAP/vulnerability-assessment-tool/blob/master/docker/README.md) guide. When I perform the `Run` stage of the documentation, the backend service fails to start. I have the following exception which explains me nothing.

```js
#docker logs d04ea50241f7
2018-12-18 10:28:50.841 ERROR 9 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: role "root" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:712) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:406) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:274) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.32.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]

2018-12-18 10:28:50.846 ERROR 9 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'dispatcherServletRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dispatcherServletRegistration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hubIntegrationController' defined in URL [jar:file:/vulas/rest-backend.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/sap/psr/vulas/backend/rest/HubIntegrationController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationRepositoryImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'appRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5368a637' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5368a637': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:
Unable to obtain database connection
------------------------------------
SQL State  : 28000
Error Code : 0
Message    : FATAL: role "root" does not exist
```

The docker containers that are up are

```html
~/vulas/vulnerability-assessment-tool# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
05a90996f80d        docker_haproxy              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:8034->7070/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8033->8080/tcp   vulas-os-haproxy
2877eeb8db76        docker_patch-lib-analyzer   "/vulas/run.sh"          7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        8080/tcp                                         vulas-os-patch-lib-analyzer
7d05307d9149        docker_frontend-bugs        "catalina.sh run"        7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        8080/tcp                                         vulas-os-frontend-bugs
84311f182d98        docker_rest-lib-utils       "/bin/sh -c 'java -D…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        8092/tcp                                         vulas-os-rest-lib-utils
a55cc03b8ee8        docker_frontend-apps        "catalina.sh run"        7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        8080/tcp                                         vulas-os-frontend-apps
45a7210170e7        docker_postgresql           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:8032->5432/tcp                           vulas-os-postgresql
```

Comment: Hello, could you try to give a `docker-compose down -v`? This commad destroys everything, also the postgres' volume. Then, could you try to set as POSTGRES_USER the string `postgres` in your `.env` file? I remind you that you should copy the `.env.sample` to a custom `.env`. Let me know, thanks.

Comment: setting the user in the env solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the above comment resolves the issue I will post an answer to give more visibility to this question.

The issue you faced was caused by a missing or changed user in the [`.env`](https://github.com/SAP/vulnerability-assessment-tool/blob/master/docker/.env.sample#L6) file used by Vulas. At [this line](https://github.com/SAP/vulnerability-assessment-tool/blob/master/docker/postgresql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-vulas-setup.sh#L4) we can see that Postgres, before creating the database, checks if both `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` are set. I can see that in your output the Postgres container started, so at some point in time in the `.env` file there were those environment variables set. Probably you changed or deleted the `POSTGRES_USER`. By doing so Vulas tried to connect to Postgres with a different user with respect to the one that created the database, thus failing to initialize the connection.

It is mandatory to modify the `.env` file before running Vulas for the first time. If you need to change the connection's parameters to the database you need to create a new one. In order to drop the current DB and create a new one give the command `docker-compose down -v` while in the `docker` folder of Vulas' repository. This will erase each volume.