# Vulas backend cannot connect to database

Tags: vulas

I am trying to run the Vulas docker setup on my local machine. I followed this [guide](https://sap.github.io/vulnerability-assessment-tool/admin/). When I perform the  Run stage of the documentation, the backend service fails to start. When the processes start, they return the following error:

```
vulas-os-rest-backend | Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
vulas-os-rest-backend | Unable to obtain database connection
vulas-os-rest-backend | ------------------------------------
vulas-os-rest-backend | SQL State  : 08004
vulas-os-rest-backend | Error Code : 0
vulas-os-rest-backend | Message    : The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
vulas-os-rest-backend | 
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:57) ~[flyway-core-5.0.7.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:67) ~[flyway-core-5.0.7.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1634) ~[flyway-core-5.0.7.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1168) ~[flyway-core-5.0.7.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.15.RELEASE]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1692) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     ... 95 common frames omitted
vulas-os-rest-backend | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:484) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:208) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:406) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:274) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1208.jre7]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.32.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.32.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:736) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.32.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:668) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.32.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.32.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.32.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.32.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.32.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.32.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:51) ~[flyway-core-5.0.7.jar!/:na]
vulas-os-rest-backend |     ... 101 common frames omitted
```

It seems to indicate an `.env` problem, however, it is configured as indicated in the installation guide. My `.env` is:

```
# Vulas
VULAS_RELEASE=3.0.15
VULAS_ENV=prod

# *** MANDATORY SETTINGS ***
# PostgreSQL
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret

# Spring (should be equal to the values in PostgreSQL section above)
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=secret

# HAProxy
HAPROXY_STATS_USER=admin
HAPROXY_STATS_PASSWORD=secret

# Frontend Bugs Frontend
FRONTEND_BUGS_USER=admin
FRONTEND_BUGS_PASSWORD=secret

# *** OPTIONAL SETTINGS ***
# Jira (optional)
JIRA_USER=
JIRA_PASSWORD=

# Proxy
HTTP_PROXY_HOST=
HTTPS_PROXY_HOST=
HTTP_PROXY_PORT=
HTTPS_PROXY_PORT=
NON_PROXY_HOSTS=
http_proxy=
https_proxy=
no_proxy=
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831226/vulas-startup-failed-with-an-exception-in-the-backend) but it didn't work!

Comment: Hello, I have a gut feeling. Could you please try to restart the entire process by giving a `docker-compose down -v`? Then could you please try to follow again the tutorial but using `postgres` as `POSTGRES_USER` and `spring.datasource.username`, instead of the current value (`admin`). I believe that the project only works when the database is used by the user 'postgres'. Let me know.

Comment: I tried with several usernames: `postgres`, `root` and `vulas` but the result was the same. Also, I tried with the new version `3.0.16-SNAPSHOT` but I still have the same error. I just hope your guts are better.

Comment: Could you please tell me you docker and docker-compose version?

Comment: ```~$ docker --version 
Docker version 18.04.0-ce, build 3d479c0 
~$ docker-compose --version 
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

Comment: Hi, could you please update your local repository to the latest changes (`git pull`) and set your `VULAS_RELEASE` equal to `3.0.16-SNAPSHOT` in your `.env` file? Thanks

Comment: Now, everything is working! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above I can understand that it was a problem with your `.env` file. Basically in your `.env` the `VULAS_RELEASE` was set to `3.0.15` but probably you built the artifacts tagged with version `3.0.15-SNAPSHOT`.

A general rule is to always check what's the `VULAS_RELEASE` in the `.env.sample` and use that value in the custom `.env`.

Consider also that at every release the `VULAS_RELEASE` is incremented, so you have to update your `.env` every time you pull the code that is on a newer release.